# Problemas ao receber lista de valores do Storage em uma variável (Ionic)

Tags: typescript, ionic

[image: Tenho os dados armazenados assim no Sotorage]

[image: Código que deveria atribuir os valores do Storage a variável prods]

Eu tenho os dados armazenados no Storage da forma que está na primeira imagem e na segunda imagem o código que deveria atribuir os valores do Storage a variável prods. Esse código está em um método que irei chamar no clique de um botão. Porém depois que chamo o método e vou imprimir o valor da variável prods, está como undefined. :(

---

Código do botão, onde é chamado o método (**add** ou **update**) dependendo da situação.

```
    <ion-button expand="block" icon-start (click)='add_or_update()'>

      <ng-template *ngIf="product.id;then btn_update; else btn_add"></ng-template>

      <ng-template #btn_update>
        <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
        Atualizar
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #btn_add>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        Adicionar
      </ng-template>

    </ion-button>
```

Método que faz a verificação de qual ação executar (**add** ou **update**)

```
add_or_update() {
  this.product.id ? this.update() : this.add();
}
```

Método **add** que vai chamar o método que contem o código com problema

```
add() {
    this.loadingService.present();
    this.product.profile = this.auth.user.profile_id;

    this.checkProductTagStorage(); // #### AQUI ####

    this.productService.add(this.product).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.loadingService.dismiss();
        this.toastService.success('Animal cadastrado com sucesso!');
        this.products.unshift(this.product);
        this.clear();
      },
      error => {
        this.loadingService.dismiss();
        this.toastService.error('Erro ao cadastrar produto!');
      }
    );
  }
```

Método em que ocorre o problema

```
  checkProductTagStorage() {
    this.prods = [];

    this.storage.get('coovita-prods-list-type-1').then((data) => {
      this.prods = data;
      console.log(this.prods); // Imprimindo a variavel está com os dados corretos
    });

    console.log(this.prods); // Imprimindo aqui a variavel está vazia []
  }
```

Comment: Seria possível por favor informar mais detalhes para reproduzirmos o problema? Talvez montar um exemplo no stackblitz ajude as outras pessoas a entenderem melhor o problema.

Comment: Recebo uma lista de produtos de uma API e depois armazeno no storage. Depois eu quero passar esses dados do storage para uma variável. O estranho é que dentro desse get da imagem se eu mandar imprimir a variável prods vai imprimir os valores corretamente. Porem fora, mesmo depois de chamar o método que faz essa requisição, se eu mandar imprimir a variável está como undefined. O que seria realmente interessante eu mostrar para ajudar?

Comment: Seria legal postar o trecho do seu template onde a variável `prods` é utilizada e o botão que ativa a função `get`. Pelo que vi até agora está tudo correto! após chamar o `get` a variável `prods` é preenchida e pode ser utilizada em outras partes do código.

Comment: Não utilizo a variável no template, eu quero esses dados só para fazer uma verificação se já existe alguma tag cadastrada com o mesmo valor. Editei a descrição e adicionei os métodos. Eu estou sem entender porque os dados estão sendo recebidos corretamente só dentro da função get. :(

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro. Vou deixar a resposta com os detalhes. Espero que ajude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao chamar a função `add()` o navegador vai interpretando linha a linha deste método.
Quando ele chega no `this.checkProductTagStorage()` ele chama essa função e já vai para a próxima
linha `this.productService.add(this.product).subscribe(...`.

Seu problema está justamente aí porque dentro do método `checkProductTagStorage` o trecho `this.storage.get`
é executado de forma assíncrona. Logo, `this.prods` é atualizado depois que o método `add()` já foi executado.

Um exemplo do que está acontecendo com seu código:

```js
let prods = null;

function add1() {
  checkProductTagStorage1();
  console.log(prods);
}

function checkProductTagStorage1() {
  // Atualiza o prods depois de 200ms
  setTimeout(() => { prods = 1; }, 200);
}

add1();
setTimeout(() => { console.log(prods); }, 200);
```

Uma das formas de resolver é utilizar uma `Promise` com o `async\await`:

```js
    let prods = null;

    async function add1() {
      await checkProductTagStorage1();
      console.log(prods);
    }

    function checkProductTagStorage1() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Atualiza o prods depois de 200ms
        setTimeout(() => {
          prods = 1;
          resolve();
        }, 200);      
      });
    }

    add1();
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(prods); }, 200);
```

No seu código seria algo do tipo:

```
async add() {
    this.loadingService.present();
    this.product.profile = this.auth.user.profile_id;

    await this.checkProductTagStorage(); // #### AQUI ####

    this.productService.add(this.product).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.loadingService.dismiss();
            this.toastService.success('Animal cadastrado com sucesso!');
            this.products.unshift(this.product);
            this.clear();
        },
        error => {
            this.loadingService.dismiss();
            this.toastService.error('Erro ao cadastrar produto!');
        }
    );
}

checkProductTagStorage() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.prods = [];

        this.storage.get('coovita-prods-list-type-1').then((data) => {
            this.prods = data;
            console.log(this.prods); // Imprimindo a variavel está com os dados corretos

            resolve(); // Indica que a promise foi resolvida
        });

        console.log(this.prods); // Imprimindo aqui a variavel está vazia []
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfeito. Eu já tinha visto o carregamento dos dados na variável sendo feito da maneira correta quando eu executava o **storage.get** no método **ionViewWillEnter**. Já estava até buscando uma explicação pra isso. Sua explicação resolveu tudo aqui :) Muito obrigado !!